# Check if a new Activity is started with Espresso

Tags: android, android-espresso

If a new Activity is lauched after my Login then I know that everything went right. I tried to implement this but I got now an

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.test.espresso.intent.Intents.internalIntended(org.hamcrest.Matcher, android.support.test.espresso.intent.VerificationMode, java.util.List)' on a null object reference
```

This is my Test class:

```
import android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule;
import android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4;

import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import static android.support.test.espresso.Espresso.onView;
import static android.support.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.click;
import static android.support.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.typeText;
import static android.support.test.espresso.intent.Intents.intended;
import static android.support.test.espresso.intent.matcher.IntentMatchers.hasComponent;
import static android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withId;

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class LoginActivityTest {

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<LoginActivity> mLoginActivityActivityTestRule =
            new ActivityTestRule<>(LoginActivity.class);

    @Test
    public void clickLoginButton_ShowsSnackBarRightCredentials() throws Exception {

        onView(withId(R.id.login_email)).perform(typeText("a@aa.aa"));
        onView(withId(R.id.login_password)).perform(typeText("11111111"));
        onView(withId(R.id.email_sign_in_button)).perform(click());

        intended(hasComponent(MainActivity.class.getName()));

    }
}
```

I found in previous questions that this line of code should help me but this line produces the NullPointer.

intended(hasComponent(MainActivity.class`enter code here`.getName()));

How can I solve this probelm? What am I doing wrong?

This is the full stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.test.espresso.intent.Intents.internalIntended(org.hamcrest.Matcher, android.support.test.espresso.intent.VerificationMode, java.util.List)' on a null object reference
at android.support.test.espresso.intent.Intents$2.check(Intents.java:190)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$2.run(ViewInteraction.java:170)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well The solution is to check this way:

```
intended(hasComponent(OnboardingActivity::class.java.name))
```

In order to perform this check, you need to add the intents library (`androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-intents:$intentsVersion")`
 and init it by calling:

`Intents.init()`

Comment: For me this is not working, the app goes to Mainactivity, but the test results with timeout.

Comment: What does `intended` do?

Answer (score 28):

Lefteris' solution or this code works:

```
intended(hasComponent(MainActivity.class.getName()));
```

**But don't forget to change `ActivityTestRule` to `IntentsTestRule` too.**

```
 @Rule
 public IntentsTestRule<LoginActivity> mLoginActivityActivityTestRule =
            new IntentsTestRule<>(LoginActivity.class);
```

Comment: How to make MainActivity ready in the foreground before use `intended(hasComponent(MainActivity.class.getName()));`? Currently i am using `Thread.sleep(2000L);` after the button click and before call intended, but i wonder, maybe there is other better way.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using `intended`, try using `intending`, it worked for mine.